# I want to allow specific users login using facebook login system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, rubygems

I`m making the online community of my University.

And I want to allow the users who goes to "ABC University" login using "facebook-omniauth".

But I don`t know how to write this logic...
Do you know how to make this logic ?

sessions controller

```
def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    session[:omniauth] = auth
    user = User.sign_in_from_facebook(auth) 
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed In"
end
```

User model

```
def self.sign_in_from_facebook(auth)
    find_by(provider: auth['provider'], uid: auth['uid'] ) || create_user_from_facebook(auth)
end

def self.create_user_from_facebook(auth)
    create(

    avatar: process_uri(auth['info']['image'] + "?width=9999"),
    email: auth['info']['email'],
    provider: auth['provider'],
    uid: auth['uid'],
    name: auth['info']['name'],
    token: auth['credentials']['token'],
    gender: auth['extra']['raw_info']['gender'],
    education: auth['extra']['raw_info']['education'],
    bio: auth['extra']['raw_info']['bio']


    )
end
```

Comment: Check against `auth['extra']['raw_info']['education']` value

Comment: There is no way to select which users would be allowed to login to your app in the first place based on this. You need to let them log in, get their education info - and then decide how your app wants to proceed from there.

Comment: I understood. thanks.